# How should I take care of this succulent?

Tags: indoors, plant-care, succulents

Please guide me in how to take care of the succulent shown in image below.  I took this picture when I got it.

It was dead in a few days, so I got a new one of the same kind. It also died. I gave it water once in a while once I observed it starting to die. I kept it in sun light, but in the next days it was completely dead.  I got another new one of the same kind but no luck in saving that plant either.

Is there anything wrong that I did, or do I need to change the soil completely and try again?  Please guide me. I really want to take care when purchasing another of the same kind.

[image]

Pictures of a dead plant are in the link below. It was died similar to the first plant but this time I haven't kept it in sun light. It was under normal room temperature. The bottom to top leaves slowly dried off in approximately 25 days.

https://photos.app.goo.gl/nPynJtQoVWKhLFrWA

Comment: How did the others die? It would be useful to know which parts started to die first and what they looked like as they died. How long did they take to die? It is likely that either light, temperature or water requirements were not being met correctly but without knowing what the symptoms were before they died it is hard for us to help.

Comment: Updated question, with link to current plant pictures.

Answer (score 2):

Let's talk a bit about succulents. In general, they are not meant to be grown indoors. That being said, certain variety's can thrive indoors given proper conditions and maintenance. In general, succulents that have bright colors (such as reds, purples and oranges) don’t do well indoors; so avoid them.

You need to give them as much sun as is physically possible and follow the "soak and dry" method for watering: https://www.succulentsandsunshine.com/how-to-water-succulent-plants/

As far as the soil you are using goes the soil you bought the plant in will be fine. You wont need to change that soil ever. You may need to get a new pot if your plant outgrows its original pot but that is a different story and doesn't require you to change the soil but simply add more.

Based on the picture you have shown I would say your succulents are being potted too deep. Note how the rim of the pot is higher than the base of the plant; eliminate that. You want the base of your plant to be getting just as much light as the top of it. In other-words the plant that is alive in the picture needs more soil.

GL!

Comment: Thanks, will try this by increasing the soil level base of the plant and will make sure "soak and dry" method.

Comment: @Paramod Np, gl!